# After defining routing in angularjs, signup form is not working

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

This is the main.html file which contains routing to the page post_es.html which contain signup form. The signup form displays the message "user created successfully" if the user is new otherwise it displays "user already exists with the same email". The problem is when post_es.html is opened through main.html than signup form doesn't work but if signup form opened directly from the url, it works properly. I want that it should work properly after opening post_es.html through main.html via routing. Please help.

Main.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJs Post Example </title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#/post_es" >Add</a>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.config( function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

        .when('/',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl : 'partial/view1.html'
        })

        .when('/post_es',
        {
            controller :'SimpleController',
            templateUrl:'post_es.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectsTo:'/'});
});


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

post_es.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>AngularJs Post Example </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #dv1{
            border:1px solid #DBDCE9; margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;width:220px;
            border-radius:7px;padding: 25px;
        }

        .info{
            border: 1px solid;margin: 10px 0px;
            padding:10px;color: #00529B;
            background-color: #BDE5F8;list-style: none;
        }
        .err{
            border: 1px solid;  margin: 10px 0px;
            padding:10px;  color: #D8000C;
            background-color: #FFBABA;   list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='dv1'>
        <form ng-controller="FrmController">
            <ul>
                <li class="err" ng-repeat="error in errors"> {{ error}} </li> 
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="info" ng-repeat="msg in msgs"> {{ msg}} </li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Sigup Form</h2>
            <div>
                <label>Name</label> 
           <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="User Name" style='margin-left: 22px;'> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="useremail" placeholder="Email" style='margin-left: 22px;'> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" ng-model="userpassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button ng-click='SignUp();' style='margin-left: 63px;margin-top:10px'>SignUp</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FrmController($scope, $http) {
            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.msgs = [];

            $scope.SignUp = function() {

                $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
                $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
               //http.post passes the data to post_es.php
                $http.post('post_es.php', {'uname': $scope.username, 'pswd': $scope.userpassword, 'email': $scope.useremail}
                ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data.msg != '')
                    {
                        $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.errors.push(data.error);

                    }
                }).error(function(data, status) { 

                    $scope.errors.push(status);

                });
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>


</html>
```

post_es.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 

$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uname);// extracting username from $data
$upswd = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pswd);
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); // creating connection with database
mysql_select_db('sample', $con);// here sample is the name of database



$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where email ="' . $uemail . '"'; 
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);

if($res['cnt']==0){ 
 $qry = 'INSERT INTO users (name,email,pass) values ("' . $usrname . '","' . $uemail . '","' . $upswd . '")'; // insert query to insert new record
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
  if ($qry_res) {
    $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => ''); 
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting record'); 
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
}
else
{
     $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
?>
```

Comment: "signup form doesn't work", can you elaborate on that? what goes wrong?

Comment: signup form doesn't work means it doesn't create new user, or doesn't show appropriate message when opened through add link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ng-submit` directive:

```
<form ng-submit="SignUp()">
```

You have a function in your controller named `SignUp`  Call the function from the `<form>` element.  Move the controller to the `<div>` element higher up in the form:

```
<div id='dv1' ng-controller="FrmController">
    <form ng-submit="SignUp()">
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems as if you're relatively new to Angular (as am I).  I think what you're doing is trying to put the routing code into a standalone .html page.  Angular doesn't work like that.  You need to put application .config code into an application JavaScript file  (e.g., app.js).  That file should then be referenced by your .html, and only "view" markup should be in the html.

If you haven't already done so, I highly recommend you work through the tutorial on AngularJS.  In particular, http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 speaks to exactly the topic you're looking to answer.